# msql fetch array no longer listing all results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch

I have a code that I have used over and over again before and now it's messing up. All I want to do is list information from the database into the table on the page, but now it will only show one result, instead of all the results it has found.

```
    <table>
    <tr><td style="background-color:#009745; color:#FFFFFF"><center><strong>Address Book</strong></center></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <?php
    $getids = mysql_query("SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM accounts WHERE s1='$id' ORDER BY id DESC", $db);
    if (mysql_num_rows($getids) > 0) {
    while ($gids = mysql_fetch_array($getids)) {
    $ab_id = $gids['id'];
    $ab_fn = $gids['first_name'];
    $ab_ln = $gids['last_name'];
    }
    ?>
    <td><a href="#"><?= $ab_id ?></a> - <?= $ab_fn . " " . $ab_ln ?></td>
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
    <td><center>No Contacts</center></td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

please help me with this.

---

Thank You for your help :)

I love this site!! I can always get answers when I need them.

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work as expected? What happens?

Comment: Execute the query you used in the database and check how many records it is returning

Comment: $id = "pwned'; drop table accounts; --"; // Make sure this $id isn't coming from user input, or if it is, that you are protecting your database from SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw two thing wrong

1. you are using mysql_fetch_array and later you are using string indexes to print the result
2. print the things in loop it is overriding values and just storing last row

   > ```
   >  if (mysql_num_rows($getids) > 0) {
   >         while ($gids = mysql_fetch_assoc($getids)) {
   >         $ab_id = $gids['id'];
   >         $ab_fn = $gids['first_name'];
   >         $ab_ln = $gids['last_name'];
   >         echo '<td><a href="#">'.$ab_id.'</a> -'. $ab_fn.''.$ab_ln.' </td>';
   >         }
   > ```

Comment: Thank You it worked :) I tried something similar before but was using mysql_fetch_array and instead of mysql_fetch_assoc like goreSplatter said. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

In this messy code you're closing the `while` loop too early:

```
while ($gids = mysql_fetch_array($getids)) {
    $ab_id = $gids['id'];
    $ab_fn = $gids['first_name'];
    $ab_ln = $gids['last_name'];
}
```

Only the last retrieved row is used later on. Also, don't use `mysql_fetch_array` if you're not accessing the numeric indeces of your result. Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead.